# FOSUBUserProvider must implement UserProviderInterface

Tags: mongodb, symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

We are trying to use  FOSUserBundle and HWIOAuthBundle together in the way like it's described there https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697

The only difference is that we are using mongodb. This error is fired:

**User provider "wf\UserBundle\Document\FOSUBUserProvider" must implement "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface"**

the FOSUBUserProvider is picked from this sample (the src is below). Is not it supposed that HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider implements Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface ?

```
<?php

namespace wf\UserBundle\Document;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface; 
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseFOSUBUserProvider;

class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseFOSUBUserProvider
{

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $property = $this->getProperty($response);
        $username = $response->getUsername();

        //on connect - get the access token and the user ID
        $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();

        $setter = 'set'.ucfirst($service);
        $setter_id = $setter.'Id';
        $setter_token = $setter.'AccessToken';

        //we "disconnect" previously connected users
        if (null !== $previousUser = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($property => $username))) {
            $previousUser->$setter_id(null);
            $previousUser->$setter_token(null);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($previousUser);
        }

        //we connect current user
        $user->$setter_id($username);
        $user->$setter_token($response->getAccessToken());

        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $username = $response->getUsername();
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($this->getProperty($response) => $username));
        //when the user is registrating
        if (null === $user) {
            $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
            $setter = 'set'.ucfirst($service);
            $setter_id = $setter.'Id';
            $setter_token = $setter.'AccessToken';
            // create new user here
            $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
            $user->$setter_id($username);
            $user->$setter_token($response->getAccessToken());
            //I have set all requested data with the user's username
            //modify here with relevant data
            $user->setUsername($username);
            $user->setEmail($username);
            $user->setPassword($username);
            $user->setEnabled(true);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
            return $user;
        }

        //if user exists - go with the HWIOAuth way
        $user = parent::loadUserByOAuthUserResponse($response);

        $serviceName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($serviceName) . 'AccessToken';

        //update access token
        $user->$setter($response->getAccessToken());

        return $user;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
          id: fos_user.user_manager
```

in 'security.yml' instead of (custom)

```
providers: 
   wf_hwi_provider:
         id: wf_user.fos_user_provider
```

does it

Answer (score 0):

`FOSUBUserProvider`  implements `AccountConnectorInterface` and  `OAuthAwareUserProviderInterface`  which are both interfaces so it not possible that they implement `UserProviderInterface`.

Checking [docs](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/oauth.xml) in  `hwioauthbundle` I found that `OAuthUserProvider` is the class that implements  `UserProviderInterface`.

https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Security/Core/User/OAuthUserProvider.php

Comment: yeah, but why does it comply?

Comment: have you tried to change `HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider` with `HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUserProvider` ?